# How can I make sure that after declaring a delegate of a protocol in Swift 5.2, that delegate is not nil when it is called?

Tags: swift5

I am trying to clear a textfield in MainViewController from the DetailViewController. I have the following code in a Swift Playground.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func bar()
}

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var detailViewControllerDelegate: DetailViewControllerDelegate!

    override func loadView() {

        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 180, height: 20)
        button.setTitle("Hello World!", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .blue

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePress), for: .touchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(button)
        self.view = view

    }


    @objc func handlePress() {
        print("\(#function)")

        if let vrvc = detailViewControllerDelegate {
            vrvc.bar()
        } else {
            print("detailViewControllerDelegate is NIL")
        }
    }

}


class MainViewController : UIViewController, DetailViewControllerDelegate {
    func bar() {
        print("Inside Bar")
    }

    override func loadView() {
        let detailViewController = DetailViewController()
        detailViewController.detailViewControllerDelegate = self
    }

}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = DetailViewController()
```

When the button is pressed, detailViewController is nil. How can I make sure that detailViewController is NOT nil when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You have two distinct `DetailViewController`s:

```
    override func loadView() {
        let detailViewController = DetailViewController()
```

`detailViewController` now references a new instance of `DetailViewController`

```
        detailViewController.detailViewControllerDelegate = self
    }

}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = DetailViewController()
```

`liveView` now references a new instance of `DetailViewController` which is *different* from the one above and in which you have not set `detailViewControllerDelegate`.

If you need to create a `DetailViewController` in one place and reference it in another you need to store a reference to it in a property that is accessible in both places.

That said, the second instance of `DetailViewController` is being created in a statement which looks like an attempt to test code in the Playground so maybe you just need to think about how you are testing.